# rails 3 tables join - assignment, activity, student

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
assignment (id, name, date)
activity (id, name, desc)
student (id, name, email)
```

An assignment can have many activities, an assignment can assign to many students.
Need to track status of each activity for a student.

So have a three primary keys table:

```
assignments_activities_students (assignment_id, activity_id, student_id, status)
```

Set the association below, but it doesn't work. Anyone know how to do this?

```
assignment
  has_many :assignments_activities_students
  has_many :students, :through => :assignments_activities_students
  has_many :activities, :through => :assignments_activities_students

activity
  has_many :assignments_activities_students
  has_many :assignments, :through => :assignments_activities_students
  has_many :students, :through => :assignments_activities_students

student
  has_many :assignments_activities_students
  has_many :assignments, :through => :assignments_activities_students
  has_many :activities, :through => :assignments_activities_students

assignments_activities_students 
  belongs_to :assignment
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :student
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What are the names of your models? There may be a problem there.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `Student` model, but you're adding relationships with

```
has_many :users, :through => :assignments_activities_students
```

You should change this to the following in your `Assignment` and `Activity` models.

```
has_many :students, :through => :assignments_activites_students
```

Comment: now suppose we need to add a student to an activity, @assignment.users=[current_user, User.find(1)], @assignment.update_attributes(@assignment), then it creates a row for :assignments_activities_users without the activity_id. anyone can help?

Comment: Cool, can you accept this answer? 

To answer your question, you need to assign an Activity to your join model. E.g. `AssignmentActivityStudent.create(:assignment => @assignment, :activity => @activity, :student => @student)`. Doing direct assignment between just two of your models, e.g. `@assignment.students = [some, students]` isn't going automatically populate the activity.